# C bind config file to executable

Tags: c, configuration, compilation, config

I have a C Programm which reads from a configuration file during runtime. This file have to be in the same Directory as the executable program. Is there a way to bind or compile the configuration file to to executable that when i copy the executable elsewhere i don't have to copy the configuration file aswell?

Comment: Placing configurations and executables in the same folder is, well, not the best design, to stay nice.

Comment: There are ways. But if you want them all listed. Your question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to bind or compile the configuration file to to executable that when i copy the executable elsewhere i don't have to copy the configuration file aswell?

It is inherent in your configuration file indeed being a separate file from your executable binary that the two can be manipulated independently.

If program configuration is performed only at compile time then yes, you can embed the configuration data into the program.  That carries the additional advantage that you then need no file I/O to access the configuration data.  That would involve your configuration process generating source code to be compiled into the program.

If yours is a conventional form of configuration file, however, meant to be adjusted some time after compilation, and maybe even by end users, then the configuration data cannot be integrated into the executable binary.  In that case, no, what you ask is not possible.  You cannot then ensure that the config file is moved or copied whenever the executable is.

Additional thoughts:

- Requiring the configuration file to be collocated with the binary is fundamentally problematic on the many systems where the location of the binary on the file system is not directly exposed to the running program.
- It is usually better for an executable to rely on a default location for its config file, independent of the location of the binary itself.  Such a default location can be system-wide, per-user, or a combination of both.
- It is fairly common for programs that rely on config files to have the ability to write a default configuration file, either automatically or in response to a special argument.  The automatic alternative is more applicable to programs with per-user configuration than to programs with global configuration, however.
- When a program is runtime-configurable via a file, it is usually a good idea to offer the option of specifying the file to use via a command-line argument.